# Error usando Api de Google para consultar direcciones

Tags: android, google-places

Estoy usando la Api de google que **sugiere direcciones de calle** a medida que uno va escribiendo la dirección. Funciona bien el 99% de las veces, pero me he topado con el siguiente error que no puedo controlar:

VIDEO DE LA EXCEPTION: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9YBeexmGSs

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cl.multicaja.checkinmc, PID: 28926
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(-1, class android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with Adapter(class cl.ejemplo.lalala.adaptadores.PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter)]
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1573)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1943)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Este es mi adaptador:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import cl.ejemplo.lalala.actividades.Actividad1;
import cl.ejemplo.lalala.actividades.Actividad2;
import cl.ejemplo.lalala.componentes.PlaceAutocomplete;
import cl.ejemplo.lalala.fragmentos.Actividad3;
import cl.ejemplo.lalala.utilidades.Logmc;

public class PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = ">>> " + PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> listaResultados;
    private Actividad1 actividad1;
    private Actividad2 actividad2;
    private Actividad3 actividad3;
    private GoogleApiClient gac;
    private AutocompleteFilter acf;

    public PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter(Actividad1 act, int resource, GoogleApiClient gac) {
        super(act.getApplicationContext(), resource);
        this.gac = gac;
        this.actividad1= act;

        Collection<Integer> tiposDeFiltro = new ArrayList<>();
        tiposDeFiltro.add(Place.TYPE_GEOCODE);
        acf = AutocompleteFilter.create(tiposDeFiltro);
    }

    public PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter(Actividad2 act, int resource, GoogleApiClient gac) {
        super(act.getApplicationContext(), resource);
        this.gac = gac;
        this.actividad2= act;

        Collection<Integer> tiposDeFiltro = new ArrayList<>();
        tiposDeFiltro.add(Place.TYPE_GEOCODE);
        acf = AutocompleteFilter.create(tiposDeFiltro);
    }

    public PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter(Actividad3 act, int resource, GoogleApiClient gac) {
        super(mapaComercios.getActivity(), resource);
        this.gac = gac;
        this.actividad3= act;

        Collection<Integer> tiposDeFiltro = new ArrayList<>();
        tiposDeFiltro.add(Place.TYPE_GEOCODE);
        acf = AutocompleteFilter.create(tiposDeFiltro);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (listaResultados == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return listaResultados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        Logmc.d(TAG, "getItem");
        return listaResultados.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                try {
                    FilterResults resultados = new FilterResults();

                    if (nuevoCheck != null) {
                        if (constraint != null && nuevoCheck.posicionActual != null) {
                            listaResultados = autocompletar(constraint);
                            if (listaResultados != null) {
                                resultados.values = listaResultados;
                                resultados.count = listaResultados.size();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (nuevaAdquirencia != null) {
                        if (constraint != null && nuevaAdquirencia.posicionActual != null) {
                            listaResultados = autocompletar(constraint);
                            if (listaResultados != null) {
                                resultados.values = listaResultados;
                                resultados.count = listaResultados.size();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (mapaComercios != null) {
                        if (constraint != null && mapaComercios.posicionActual != null) {
                            listaResultados = autocompletar(constraint);
                            if (listaResultados != null) {
                                resultados.values = listaResultados;
                                resultados.count = listaResultados.size();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return resultados;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                try {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        };
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> autocompletar(CharSequence constraint){
        try {
            if (gac.isConnected()) {
                LatLngBounds cuadradoBusqueda = null;
                if (nuevoCheck != null)             cuadradoBusqueda = nuevoCheck.obtenerCuadradoDeBusqueda();
                else if (nuevaAdquirencia != null)  cuadradoBusqueda = nuevaAdquirencia.obtenerCuadradoDeBusqueda();
                else if (mapaComercios != null)     cuadradoBusqueda = mapaComercios.obtenerCuadradoDeBusqueda();

                //Logmc.d(TAG, "Iniciando consulta de autocompletado para: " + constraint.toString());
                //Logmc.d(TAG, "Cuadrado de búsqueda: " + cuadradoBusqueda.toString());
                PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> resultados =
                        Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(
                                gac,
                                constraint.toString(),
                                cuadradoBusqueda,
                                acf
                        );

                AutocompletePredictionBuffer acpb = resultados.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                final Status estado = acpb.getStatus();
                if (!estado.isSuccess()) {
                    Logmc.e(TAG, "Error al contactar API: " + estado.toString());
                    acpb.release();
                    return null;
                }

                //Logmc.d(TAG, "Consulta completada. Se recibieron " + acpb.getCount() + " predicciones");
                Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterador = acpb.iterator();
                ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> listaResultados = new ArrayList<>(acpb.getCount());
                while (iterador.hasNext()) {
                    AutocompletePrediction prediccion = iterador.next();

                    PlaceAutocomplete pac = new PlaceAutocomplete(
                            prediccion.getPlaceId(),
                            prediccion.getDescription()
                    );
                    if(pac.toString().contains(", Chile"))  // TO/DO: 08-03-2017 SOLO ACEPTAMOS DIRECCIONES DE CHILE
                        listaResultados.add(pac);
                }

                acpb.release();

                return listaResultados;
            }
            Logmc.e(TAG, "Cliente Google API no está conectado para consultas de autocompletado.");
            return null;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

y este es el PlaceAutocomplete

```
public class PlaceAutocomplete {

    public CharSequence placeId;
    public CharSequence description;

    public PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description.toString();
    }
}
```

y así la llamo en las actividades:

```
public class Actividad3 extends Fragment implements InterfazConsulta, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

protected GoogleApiClient gac;                              //Autocompletado de direcciones
private PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter pacra;                 //Rows de direcciones que aparecen al escribir la direccion
/*blabla*/


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*blabla*/
    // AUTOCOMPLETADO DE DIRECCION
    gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(fragmentActivity)
        .enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity, 0 /* clientId */, this)
        .enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity, 0 /* clientId */, this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .build();
gac.connect();
/*blabla*/
}

//Buscador
private void buscaDireccion(){
    //buscar en el mapa
    final MaterialAutoCompleteTextView input = new MaterialAutoCompleteTextView(fragmentActivity);
    input.setPaddings(20, 0, 10, 0);

    //SUGIERE LA DIRECCIÓN, PERO SOLO FUNCIONA CON INTERNET
    input.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                final PlaceAutocomplete item = pacra.getItem(position);
                if(item != null) {
                    final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "placeId: " + placeId);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "item.description: " + item.description);
                    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(gac, placeId);
                    placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Consulta no fue completada. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                                places.release();
                                return;
                            }
                            final Place place = places.get(0);
                            if (place.getLatLng() != null && lat != null && lon != null) {
                                Location posicionLugar = new Location("");
                                posicionLugar.setLatitude(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                                posicionLugar.setLongitude(place.getLatLng().longitude);
                                Location posicionActual = new Location("");
                                posicionActual.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(lat));
                                posicionActual.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lon));
                            }
                            places.release();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    });
    pacra = new PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter(Actividad3.this, R.layout.row_place, gac);
    input.setAdapter(pacra);

    final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(fragmentActivity)
            .setTitle("Ingresa una dirección")
            //.setMessage("Recuerde incluir el número luego de la calle.")
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.buscar_warning)
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    Editable value = input.getText();
                    if (!value.toString().equals("")) {
                        Estadisticas.upMapaBuscarLupa(fragmentActivity);
                        new BuscaDireccionTask().execute(fragmentActivity, value.toString(), -56.16696465022672, -77.156982421875, -17.177530993362254, -67.049560546875);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            })
            .show();

    //Sube el builder para que se vean las sugerencias
    input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(builder.getWindow() != null) {
                builder.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Necesito controlar el error...
la forma en que replico el error es ingresando un texto por ejemplo: "Fitrono " y luego borrar el último espacio y lo vuelvo a ingresar, borrarlo y volverlo a ingresar hasta que muera.

La dependecia que tengo en el gradle es:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

---

**EDITADO (29/03/2017)**
**OBSERVACIONES:**

- El exception **solo ocurre** cuando tecleo con las dos manos. Es extraño, pero si replico la misma prueba del video con un dedo, nunca se cae la aplicación. *Dicho esto creo que una posible solución seria modificar el comportamiento del editText (en mi caso se llama input) para que permita teclear una tecla a la vez (?)*.
- Añadí Logs en todo el adaptador y al último método que entra es a **getCount()**, pero ni agregandole un try-catch he logrado capturar la exception

**EDITADO (03/04/2017)**

- De momento me quedo con mi solución, pero seguiré en espera de una respuesta mejor.

Comment: No veo en el código donde llamas este método: `publishResults ...` ¿? Es muy probable que el error venga por ahí.

Comment: esta en el Filter() (pulsa CONTROL + F y escribe publishResults).... estuve llenado de logs el adaptador y me doy cuenta que se cae justo antes de entrar al publishResults. Creo que ocurre porque pulso muy rápido o casi al mismo tiempo las teclas espacio y borrar, es como si entrara a dos listener

Comment: Veo el método `publishResults` pero no veo que le llames en ningún momento, al menos en el código que has compartido.

Comment: es parte del filterable que implementa la actividad

Comment: Lo que dice el mensaje es que esa parte debe estar en el hilo de la interfaz gráfica, no en el hilo del background.

Comment: pero el LisView del que habla el error no existe en mi actividad. Retomando un poco la pregunta anterior, acá responden lo de publishResults http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249608/google-places-autocomplete-api-threading/16249642#16249642 y esta es la documentacion que se cita https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/widget/Filter.html?hl=id#performFiltering

Comment: El error te dice claramente que el ListView no está siendo notificado de los cambios, no está ocurriendo esto `notifyDataSetChanged();` Creo que tu solución apunta por ahí. Mira esta respuesta, en el Update, o sea, al final : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9820129/5587982

Comment: mira el video que adjunte al comienzo de la pregunta, en él se ve que funciona el place autocomplete, en estos momentos tengo todo lleno de Logs y sí entra a los casos del publishResults... el problema ocurre cuando pulso muy rápido el espacio y borrar, es como que el adaptador se mareara y entra por dos eventos a la vez

Comment: _es como que el adaptador se mareara y entra por dos eventos a la vez_ Precisamente ese es el problema. No debe tener entrada por dos eventos, sino por uno solo, que me parece debe ser la parte de la interfaz gráfica UI. No tengo experiencia con la Api de Google Places para poder decirte exactamente dónde podría estar el error, pero ya que conoces más o menos la lógica de tu programa ¿por qué no controlas que los datos se actualicen desde un sólo sitio? Además, eso es lo que te está indicando el mensaje de error.

Comment: El problema definitivamente es el listener. Cual es tu Activity inicial? @Maguz

Comment: Mi actividad inicial es un spashactivity y luego a una activity llamada login o a Root  (si ya se esta logeado) echale un vistazo al video del exception

Comment: @Maguz veo que acabas de agregar un bounty aún mayor, en verdad es un issue importante, me hubieras comentado para ayudarte ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ y no dieras un bounty tan grande ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏ veo el video...

Comment: por curiosidad, cuál es la data que estás ingresando ?

Comment: @fredyfx en el video y en la descripción del problema se ve: ... la forma en que replico el error es ingresando un texto por ejemplo: "Fitrono " y luego borrar el último espacio y lo vuelvo a ingresar, borrarlo y volverlo a ingresar hasta que muera.

Answer (score 3):

**Solución (mas o menos)**

Debido a que el adaptador se estaba mareando al recibir tan seguido los cambios del texto, trate de implementar un método que desconectara el gac cuando se escribe muy rápido

```
    input.setAdapter(pacra); //justo despues de esta linea que esta en la pregunta 
    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private Timer timer2 = new Timer();
        private final long DELAY = 1000; // milliseconds
        private final long DELAY2 = 500; // milliseconds
        private Long startTime = null, difference = null;

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Logmc.d(TAG, ">> afterTextChanged: ["+s+"]");

            if(startTime == null) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }else{
                difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Logmc.d(TAG, "difference: "+difference);
                if(difference < 200){
                    Logmc.d(TAG, "MUY RÁPIDO!");

                    gac.disconnect();
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(
                            new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Logmc.d(TAG, "!!!!!!!!");
                                    if(!gac.isConnected()){
                                        gac.connect();
                                        resetearTexto();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            DELAY
                    );
                }else{
                    timer.cancel();
                    if(!gac.isConnected()){
                        gac.connect();
                        resetearTexto();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void resetearTexto(){
            try {
                //esperamos 500 ms para resetear texto y que vuelva a buscar direcciones
                timer2.cancel();
                timer2 = new Timer(); //esperamos que el gac este bien conectado
                timer2.schedule(
                        new TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (input.getText().length() != 0) {
                                            input.setText("" + input.getText());
                                            input.setSelection(input.getText().length()); //focus in right of text
                                        }
                                        startTime = null;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        DELAY2
                );
            }catch (Exception e){ Logmc.e(TAG, "ERROR!", e); }
        }
    });
```

Lo malo de esta solución es que hay que implementarlo en todos los editText que muestras las sugerencias pero hasta el momento cumple como solución y no se ha vuelto a caer **EDITO: aun se cae pero mucho menos :(!**

Answer (score 1):

El problema especificado es:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls
>   notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(-1,
>   class android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with
>   Adapter(class
>   cl.ejemplo.lalala.adaptadores.PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter)]

y es debido a que el método:

```
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
```

se ejecuta en background y a partir de ese método se estan cambiando los resultados de `listaResultados` que son necesarias para el Adapter. **No se debe modificar desde un Thread en background.**

---

Revisando tu clase esta puede ser optimizada, de hecho no necesitas 3 métodos para que reciban un tipo diferente de Activity, puede ser un único método que reciba el contexto de la Activity sin importar cual sea. Además de esto puedes agregar la clase `PlaceAutocomplete` dentro de tu clase principal `PlacesAutocompleteRowAdapter`.

Comment: uso el nombre de la actividad en lugar del contexto porque estoy llamando **obtenerCuadradoDeBusqueda()** declarado en cada actividad con parámetros como la latitud y longitud actuales y en lo otro si creo que tienes razón, pero esto no solucionaría el problema. Y en otro tema aparte, añadiré observaciones a la pregunta de mis pruebas que llevo.

Comment: Para obtener el valor new LatLngBounds simplemente necesitas llamar un método que retorne lo que tienes como valor en obtenerCuadradoDeBusqueda() de cada Activity y esto lo envies como parametro al Adapter, lo comento porque es la forma en la cual lo realizo. Mi respuesta comenta cual es el problema, porque razón se cierra la aplicación.

Comment: Mi implementación tiene el mismo problema pero no se cierra tan facilmente, estoy revisando como arreglar mi problema para comentarte como lo realicé en la respuesa..

Comment: también usas 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0' ? la mia no se cierra facilmente, como edite en la pregunta, solo ocurre al teclear con más de un dedo

Comment: hola @Maguz si, uso   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0' pero no es facil que se cierre la aplicación, en realidad no habia notado ese detalle, hasta que vi tu pregunta =), creo que tengo que resolverlo tambièn.

Answer (score 0):

El thread que coge el resultado mediante el callback, no es el thread del GUI.

En onResult(), no hagas nada, solo enviar "places" con un evento de GUI al thread de GUI. No modifiques ni el modelo ni la vista desde onResult().

No se muy bien como se envian eventos al GUI en Android...

view.post(); // creo que con esto....

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      ......
   }
});
```

Comment: la parte de la que hablas está es el **input.setOnItemClickListener**, es decir, cuando doy clic en una ítem de la lista... la exception ocurre antes, al mostrarla, te sugiero ver el vídeo de la exception